# How to throw errors properly in C# with using() or try catch?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, try-catch, using

So I have some code and I am curious how it is best to catch the errors. Should I make a query wrapped in a using which is then wrapped in a try catch? I am thinking the below is that correct?

```
    try
    {
        using (db)
        {
            string salt = BCryptHelper.GenerateSalt(6);
            var hashedPassword = BCryptHelper.HashPassword(user.Password, salt);

            User newUser = new User
            {
                EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress,
                PasswordSalt = salt,
                PasswordHash = hashedPassword,
                CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            db.Users.Add(newUser);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException exp)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Steam Id could not be added", exp);
    }
```

Comment: looks fine to me.  what are you concerned about?  There is no expense of having a try/catch.  The cost occurs throwing exceptions.

Comment: awesome i just didnt know if the using will error and not get to the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping it in a `try`, `catch` and possibly a `finally` to clean up anything that may need cleaning up is the right way to do it.

Wrapping it in a `using` will not implement any exception handling but will just dispose of the field that you have contained in the `using` that implements `IDisposable` after you leave the scope of the using `statement`.

Answer (score 1):

The `try...catch` (and optional `finally`) are always guaranteed by the runtime to be used; this is particularly important with `finally` statements [(documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx).  The same is also true for a `using` block [(reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

I would, however, restructure your code such that non-database specific operations are handled outside the try/catch - that way you won't open up a connection to the database only to have something else fail before you need it.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot, `throw new Exception` ,  `throw ex`, `throw` they all have their own significance, have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET) for more detail.

Answer (score -2):

The try catch can not catch exception happen within the using block. This cause the system to crash with unhandled exception.

Below is much guarantee from crashes. I am not sure this is due to Entity Framework. Which is quite weird to me.

```
using (var entities = new AttritionRateEntities())
{
   try
   {
      var ent = entities.AttritionRatePerSetups.FirstOrDefault(
```

Comment: Actually it can. A using block is just an easy way of writing `try{}finally{Dispose}`. The exception gets rethrown at the end of it and can be cought by the outher `catch`

Comment: No, using is not for try catch. It only meant for to remember us to call Dispose for object inheriting IDisposable.